# Django taggit: How to allow multi-word tags

Tags: django

Django-taggit automatically splits a tag like "software engineering" into ["software", "engineering"]. The app I'm writing tags a certain data structure by the full names of people who have seen it, so splitting "FirstName LastName" at a space would be incorrect.

How can I override this behavior?

I'm assuming it would be something along the lines of a custom widget that cleans the input by splitting at commas, but I can't figure out how to make that interact with taggit, or how to set it up to begin with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'm not sure which version of taggit you are using but mine (0.12) doesn't split tags like you imply, it also matches on slug rather then name.

Comment: [Here's the taggit docs](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html). It won't split "First1 Last1, First2 Last2" because it has one comma, but if I just wanna enter "First Last", since there's no comma, it'll split it

Comment: There's no need to use the form field provided by taggit with your use case, why not simply use a forms.CharField and process the payload manually?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, but I don't know how to transfer the data from the charfield into a taggit model.

Comment: are you trying it with the quotes? according to their docs, it should work as a single entry with quotes

Comment: I'm aware, but I'm aiming to make it a bit more user-friendly

Comment: This is a totally valid question. None of the comments above are helpful. Taggit DOES split tags like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if django-taggit had this back when you asked, but I'd like to provide an answer (year 2021) as I just faced this same issue.

### Step 1

I had a *tags* app within my project. If you don't, you can really put this anywhere. You will just need the "dotted path" later.

**tags/utils.py**

```
def custom_tag_string(tag_string):
    """ takes in a string, returns a list """
    if not tag_string:
        return []
    if ',' not in tag_string:
        return [tag_string]
    return [t.strip() for t in tag_string.split(',')]
```

### Step 2

You need the dotted path to the `custom_tag_string` utility function.

**settings.py**

```
TAGGIT_TAGS_FROM_STRING = 'tags.utils.custom_tag_string'
```

This works because django-taggit provides a way to override the `taggit.utils._parse_tags` function that comes with taggit. More [documentation can be found here](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html#using-a-custom-tag-string-parser).